# Passing a vector of method pointers to another method for execution

Tags: rust

I would like to pass in a vector of method pointers to `run_all` to be executed on some `i32` data.

The struct `Comp` has no static errors but I'm not sure if `a(self, 7)` is how it is supposed to be called.

```
pub struct Comp;

impl Comp {
    pub fn talk(&self, i: i32) {
        println!("talking = {}", i);
    }

    pub fn run_all(&self, fn_vec: Vec<&fn(&Self, i32)>) {
        for a in fn_vec.into_iter() {
            a(self, 7);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_comp = Comp;

    let my_vec: Vec<&fn(&Self, i32)> = Vec::new();
    my_vec.push(my_comp.talk);
    my_vec.push(my_comp.talk);

    my_comp.run_all(my_vec);
}
```

```
error[E0411]: cannot find type `Self` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:18:26
   |
18 |     let my_vec: Vec<&fn(&Self, i32)> = Vec::new();
   |                          ^^^^ `Self` is only available in impls, traits, and type definitions

error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `talk` on type `Comp`
  --> src/main.rs:19:25
   |
19 |     my_vec.push(my_comp.talk);
   |                         ^^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
19 |     my_vec.push(my_comp.talk(_));
   |                             ^^^

error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `talk` on type `Comp`
  --> src/main.rs:20:25
   |
20 |     my_vec.push(my_comp.talk);
   |                         ^^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
20 |     my_vec.push(my_comp.talk(_));
   |                             ^^^
```

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=402e20e88a8202df0212fae14e7af88f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference the methods over the type (`MyType::my_method`), not the instance. It needs some adjustments too:

```rust
pub struct Comp;

impl Comp {
    pub fn talk(&self, i: i32) {
        println!("talking = {}", i);
    }

    pub fn run_all(&self, fn_vec: Vec<fn(&Self, i32)>) {
        for a in fn_vec.into_iter() {
            a(self, 7);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_comp = Comp;

    let mut my_vec: Vec<fn(&Comp, i32)> = Vec::new();
    my_vec.push(Comp::talk);
    my_vec.push(Comp::talk);

    my_comp.run_all(my_vec);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=034ede7a805ac5b1a408f2dbc5fb6770)

Comment: Please look for duplicate questions and answers before answering.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I'm sorry, just saw your comment after replying.

Comment: @Netwave I don't follow the connection — why would you wait for a comment before searching for duplicates?

Comment: @Shepmaster, I got confused too. It didn't updated to being close, and I thought you were referring to the comment on the question where there is a playground link. Sorry for the mess :)

Comment: @netwave, well your simple explanation of "Reference the methods over the type (MyType::my_method)," made me understand where I went wrong in my code. Even though the question is duplicate, this answer made it more clear for me. And because I'm learning.  Thank you for the playground